# Code works in Java but not Python?

Tags: python, recursion

This code seems to work in Java, but when I convert it to Python, it exceeds the maximum recursion depth and exits.. Not sure what the difference is. They look like they function identically to me.

**Java version:**

```
public String addCommas(String number)
{
  if(number.length < 4
  {
    return number;
  }
  return addCommas(number.subString(0, number.length - 3)) + "," + number.subString(number.length - 3, number.length);
}
```

**Python version:**

```
def addCommas(number):
    number = str(number)
    if len(number) < 4:
        return number
    else:
        return addCommas(number[:len(number) - 3] + ',' + number[len(number) - 3:])
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Removing the Java tag assuming you don't want the answer in Java.

Comment: Your parentheses are different. The call to `addCommas` should end after `number[:len(number) - 3]` but it doesn't. `return addCommas(number[:len(number) - 3]) + ',' + number[len(number) - 3:]`

Comment: I feel very dumb right now, thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the last line.

```
 return addCommas(number.subString(0, number.length - 3)) + "," + number.subString(number.length - 3, number.length);
```

This calls `addCommas` on the first substring only (which reduces the length of the string parameter for the next call by 3) and then appends a comma and the last three digits to its result.

```
 return addCommas(number[:len(number) - 3] + ',' + number[len(number) - 3:])
```

This on the other hand first adds a comma and calls `addCommas` on the whole new string (which is even longer than the original, resulting in the infinite recursion loop).

```
 return addCommas(number[:len(number) - 3]) + ',' + number[len(number) - 3:]
```

This would work as it only calls `addCommas` on the first substring and adds the commas to the result of `addCommas`, the same way the Java code does it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the last line

Java :
return addCommas(number.subString(0, number.length - 3)) + "," + number.subString(number.length - 3, number.length);

Python :
return addCommas(number[:len(number) - 3] + ',' + number[len(number) - 3:])

are not same. If you observe in java you are calling addCommas and then appending comma and a string. Whereas in python you are only calling addCommas function.This will lead to infinite loop. Just do it same as in java.

return addCommas(number[:len(number) - 3] + ',' + number[len(number) - 3:])